# Is there a way to hide the INSTANCE variable on a Kotlin singleton object

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop

If I have code like this

```
object ObjectTest {
    @JvmStatic
    fun init() {

    }
}
```

is it possible to hide the `ObjectTest.INSTANCE` variable that Kotlin automatically generates? I don't want the object to be accessible via an instance and nor will it have any instance methods, so the `INSTANCE` variable is just polluting autocomplete and could be confusing to potential users (This code is for a library that will be consumed by others).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, by converting an `object` into a plain file.

```
@file:JvmName("ObjectTest")
// maybe a package statement here
fun init() {
  // here `init` is public static final void
}
```

And there's no `INSTANCE` object. In Kotlin this is a top-level function, but in Java it's a class named `ObjectTest` with a private constructor and it has a `public static final void` method called `init`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! As a follow up, for my specific use case, if I then wanted to split the methods of this into multiple files (but still accessible to Java via ObjectTest.x for all methods) how would I go about doing that, if at all? I was attempting to use 


    ```@file:JvmMultifileClass
    @file:JvmName("ObjectTest")```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick for multifile. Is it because the annotation only works for classes and now this is no longer a class? Would there be a way to do what I'm asking in the original question and have a multifile class?

Comment: @vanshg `@file:JvmMultifileClass` works when multiple files are all annotated with `@file:JvmMultifileClass` and `@file:JvmName("ObjectTest")`. This works, always.